# Caligraphy on a painting

Tags: calligraphy

This inscription appears on a painting.

Assuming it's Chinese, what would it say:

- in simplified characters?
- in English translation?

[image]

Comment: You may wish to show the whole painting to see if it fits the painter's list of authenticated ones?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be:

宇基 - Yuki (the artist's name)

於 - at

香江 - Hong Kong

雅風畫苑 - Yafeng (Elegant Wind/Style) Painting Workshop/Gallery

*The Artist might be the Chinese-American painter named [胡宇基](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%83%A1%E5%AE%87%E5%9F%BA/10735193) who was born in 1927*

Comment: 應該是「香」江吧（請參考：https://www.cidianwang.com/shufa/xiang5135_cs.htm）。香江是香港的雅稱。

Comment: I agree. Changed to Hong Kong